# Echo print literal codes in web page. [PHP]

Tags: php, session, syntax, session-variables

I'm having a hard time figuring out what's wrong with my php code regarding the passing of variables or perhaps regarding my php syntax. So this is the php containing start_session();. These are located at the top of those pages that need to share variables.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
session_start();
$CustNum = $_SESSION['CustNum'];
$UserName = $_SESSION['UserName'];
?>
```

Then this is the body code.

```
<?php
if($UserName && $UserID)
    echo ("Welcome <b>$UserName</b>. <br> <a href='index.php'><b>Log Out</b></a>");
else
    echo ("Please log in to access this page.<br><a href='login.php'>Log In Here</a>");
```

?>

This is the result printed in the web page:

```
"$UserName. 
 Log Out"); else echo ("Please log in to access this page.
 Log In Here"); ?> "
```

Can anyone tell me what the problem is. Thank you!

Comment: If you're seeing the literal PHP code on the web page, you must have an extraneous quote somewhere.

Comment: Can you had your full code to pastebin so that we can take a look at it

Comment: Are you running this on a computer that has PHP installed?  It looks like it is not being interpreted.  On the page where you see the bad output, click View Source and do you see the entire PHP script with <?php tags?